# Can't maximize chrome window using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried to maximize the window onPreapre by the command below:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

But it doesn't maxmize the window and there's no error on selenium webdriver logs, actually it seems like the execute has been succeed -

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6) on port 5814
Only local connections are allowed.
17:14:28.898 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome, chromeOptions={args=[--no-sandbox, --test-type, --memory-metrics, --console, --crash-on-failure], prefs={download={directory_upgrade=true, default_directory=./Users/Idan/automation/tests/downloaded/, prompt_for_download=false}}}}]]
17:14:28.909 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 90000])
17:14:28.910 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 90000]
17:14:28.969 INFO - Executing: [maximise window])
17:14:29.236 INFO - Done: [maximise window]
17:14:29.244 INFO - Executing: [maximise window])
17:14:29.250 INFO - Done: [maximise window]
```

Comment: Did you tried to apply `ChromeOptions` like `"--start-maximized"` or `"--kiosk"`?

Answer (score 6):

You can try it with [start-maximized](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#start-maximized) flag:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['start-maximized']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I remember we had a similar issue - what we did is *first set the size of the window and then maximize* - don't remember exactly why did we apply this workaround, but it works for us:

```
browser.manage().window().setSize(1400, 900);
browser.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your log - you do maximization twice. Maybe the first time it is maximized, and after the second try it is restored down to default size

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do this.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(x, y);");
```

'x' and 'y' depends on your screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to maximize a chrome app is through JavaScript. Try this:

```
//Maximizing Chrome App Window.
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("window.resizeTo(1366, 768);");
```

Change the parameters 1366, 768 according to your monitor settings/setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with our `browser.manage().window().setSize(1024, 768);`, but when I used a better ratio it worked fine `browser.manage().window().setSize(1200, 800);`

Not sure this will help anyone but hope it does.

Answer (score 0):

Were facing the same kind of problem and solved using this snippet: (Java)

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```

**Screen goes in the fullscreen mode, and you will not be able to see the address bar, all you will see is the content of the page.